# Ordernar consulta Mysql usando order By

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, orderby

Necesito ordenar una consulta siguiendo algunos parámentros

1-) que se ordene por fecha de registro

2-) si es un privado o dealer (ownertype_id) 1 = private 2 = dealer

3-) si el dealer tiene una suscripcion "premium" o no

```
SELECT 
vehicles.id,
/*vehicles.year,
models.model,
makes.make,
vehicles.price,*/
vehicles.created_at,
vehicles.dealer_id,
dealers.id as dealers_ID,
dealers.dealer,
vehicles.vendor,
dealers.vendor_id as vendorId_Dealer,
dealers.subscription,
vehicles.ownertype_id,
ownertypes.name AS ownertype,
contacts.email AS contact_email,
contacts.name AS contact_name
FROM
vehicles
    INNER JOIN
models ON vehicles.model_id = models.id
    INNER JOIN
makes ON models.make_id = makes.id
LEFT JOIN
contacts ON vehicles.contact_id = contacts.id
LEFT JOIN
ownertypes ON vehicles.ownertype_id = ownertypes.id
LEFT JOIN dealers 
    on vehicles.vendor_id LIKE  dealers.dealer_id
WHERE
vehicles.status_id = 1
ORDER BY  vehicles.created_at DESC,  FIELD(dealers.subscription,'premium','free') DESC, ownertypes.id ASC
```

Esta es la consulta Necesito es que la 4ta fila destacada en verde vaya arriba

EL orden seria

POr orden de creacion dando prioridad a los ownertype 1 luego a los ownertype 2 y dentro de esos ownertype 2 los que tiene subscription tipo premium.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si quieres primero las fechas más recientes tienes que cambiar  `DESC` por `ASC` en el orden del campo `created_at`, es decir: **`ORDER BY vehicles.created_at ASC, FIELD(dealers.subscription,'premium','free') DESC, ownertypes.id ASC`**

Comment: Por fecha esta perfecto necesito es que me coloque el premium de primero

es decir 
premium 2
null 2